# Can't draw square to canvas using setInterval?

Tags: javascript

Hey Guys I'm trying to draw a square to the canvas every 70ms using setInterval. The Interval is set to call `function draw()` this function has the fillRect() method inside it. But I can't get it to work any ideas? Oh and I tried clearRect() and that didn't work.

```js
//declare global variables
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');

//set canvas context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//put canvas dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake and set starting position
let snake = [{
 x : cvsW/2,
 y : cvsH/2
}]

//create a variable to store the direction of the snake
let direction;

//add event to read users input then change direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 if(e.keycode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keycode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keycode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keycode == 38 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
})

//move snake in chosen direction
if(direction == 'left') snake[0].x -= unit;
else if(direction == 'right') snake[0].x += unit;
else if(direction == 'up') snake[0].y -= unit;
else if(direction == 'down') snake[0].y += unit;

function draw() {
 ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
 ctx.fillRect(snake[0].x - unit/2, snake[0].y - unit/2, unit, unit);
}


setInterval(70, draw);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  #canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="768" height="512"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by can't get it to work. Please clearly state what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some bugs in your code, but I think this is what you meant:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Snake</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #333;
        }

        #canvas {
            background-color: #4d4d4d;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="768" height="512"></canvas>
    <script>
        //declare global variables
        const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');

        //set canvas context
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        //put canvas dimensions into variables
        const cvsW = canvas.width;
        const cvsH = canvas.height;

        //create snake unit
        const unit = 16;

        //create snake and set starting position
        let snake = [{
            x : cvsW/2,
            y : cvsH/2
        }]

        //create a variable to store the direction of the snake
        let direction;

        //add event to read users input then change direction
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
            else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
            else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
            else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';

            //move snake in chosen direction
            if (direction == 'left') snake[0].x -= unit;
            else if (direction == 'right') snake[0].x += unit;
            else if (direction == 'up') snake[0].y -= unit;
            else if (direction == 'down') snake[0].y += unit;

            console.log(e.keyCode, direction);
        })

        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
            ctx.fillRect(snake[0].x - unit/2, snake[0].y - unit/2, unit, unit);
            console.log('oi');
        }


        setInterval(draw, 70);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please notice:

1. Argument order of `setInterval`
2. Case sensitivity of `event.keyCode`